# Error trying to update database after module update

Tags: 7, updating

After I update a module, and click at http://omroepzuidplas.nl/admin/update/ready on the 'run' button to do the database updates. Drupal sends me to this url:

http://omroepzuidplas.nl/http%253A//omroepzuidplas.nl/authorize.php%3Fbatch%3D1?op=start&id=2796

Which result in an 404 page not found error.

I use Drupal 7.50 on CentOS7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is likely either that the `RewriteBase` is not set in .htaccess, or the `base_url` is not set in settings.php.  Likely you can bypass the settings problem if you go directly to http://omroepzuidplas.nl/update.php.

To do database updates you have to be logged in as User 1 (often called admin or super admin, but it could have any user name).